# Why won't my query be inserted to my DB?

Tags: php, mysql, html, database

I've created a query to insert a few certain values into my database:

```
function upload_text($text, $categories) {
$idea = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($text));
$categories = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($categories));
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `textfiles` VALUES ('', '".$_SESSION['user_id']."', '$text', '$categories', UNIX_TIMESTAMP() )"); }
```

The informaton submitted through the query is gathered by a user input PHP/HTML site, which consists of the following code (shortened):

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">
<font size='2' face='arial'>Your text:
<textarea cols="150" rows="5" name="text" maxlenght='500'></textarea>
<font size='2' face='arial'>Categories:
<textarea cols="150" rows="1" name="categories" maxlenght='100'></textarea>
<input type='submit' name='sub' value='Submit'>  </form>

if (isset($_POST['sub'])) {
$text = $_POST['text'];
$categories = $_POST['categories'];
$upload = upload_text($text, $categories);
      exit();
```

}

When I test my site in through localhost, and submit text, as I would expect a user to do, no text is actually transfered to my database. It remains empty.

Would someone please help me understand what errors I have in my code, or what misstakes I'm doing, because I can't seem to find them.

Thank you.

Comment: Try checking the error log (for apache, that'd be error.log).

Comment: I don't see a mysql_connect()

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Is the upload_text function executed on submit? Do you have columns in textfiles that can not be empty? What is mysql_error saying?

Comment: Sounds like database permissions; check the log as mentioned.

Comment: you know that this has a sqlinjection? try to echo the query before insert, if the query is not echoed then the query isn't executed. if the query echoes then add the echoed query here as a comment

Comment: What is the sql query you are trying to execute, echo it so that you can see if the fields are empty? Paste your code so we can see it.

Comment: Would the thumbs down, care for an explanation what I could do to improve my question?

Comment: Trampi, would you please explain what you mean by echoing out the query, before insert. Would you mind just putting together a short code snippet, as an example?

Comment: @NorS See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214802/why-wont-my-query-be-inserted-to-my-db/7214859#7214859 for how to echo out the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function needs to be wrapped in curly braces:

```
function upload_text($text, $categories) {
    $idea = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($text));
    $categories = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($categories));
    $SQL = "INSERT INTO `textfiles` 
            VALUES ('', 
                    '".$_SESSION['user_id']."', 
                    '$text', 
                    '$categories',
                    UNIX_TIMESTAMP() 
                   )";
    echo $SQL;
    mysql_query($SQL);
}
```

You must also already have an active connection to your DB server for this to work.

It would also be very useful to see what your SQL looks like before the query is run *so* using my code above `echo` out `$SQL` just before it is fed to `mysql_query()`.

As a good first step for debugging I suggest you enable error logging at the top of your script:

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I actually just missed copying those. They're in there.

Comment: @NorS I have added more debugging tips, but you really need to edit your question and ensure that the actual code you have is pasted there so that we can have a chance of helping you.

Comment: You still have not supplied a printout of your query though :(

Answer (score 0):

Please put the function contents inside braces in the code given

```
function upload_text($text, $categories)
{
$idea = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($text));
$categories = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($categories));
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `textfiles` VALUES ('', '".$_SESSION['user_id']."', '$text', '$categories', UNIX_TIMESTAMP() )");
}
```

also you are not closing the brace open at:

```
 if (isset($_POST['sub'])) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `textfiles` VALUES ('', '".$_SESSION['user_id']."', '$text', '$categories', UNIX_TIMESTAMP() )"); }
```

with this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `textfiles` VALUES ('', '".$_SESSION['user_id']."', '$text', '$categories', UNIX_TIMESTAMP() )") or die(mysql_error()); }
```

to detect the error. Then debug..